# Django-Activity-Stream in Admin

Tags: python, django, activity-streams

I am trying to implement django-activity-stream and got all the way to implementing actions. (http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/actions.html)

So far this is the action I have:

```
def schedules_concert(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    action.send(instance, verb='scheduled a concert')

post_save.connect(schedules_concert, sender=Band)
```

What is not clear to me is where I should add the triggers for the actions. All the data in the app is inserted through the admin interface, so where should I call the action.send command?

Comment: You can have them in `admin.py` as they will be imported when the application loads

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony but then how can I trigger the send events when a record changes to "Published" status for example? I thought this would have to be done by overriding the save method of the model or something like that.